# Morphism between Irreducible Curves has Finite Fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes

Let $C, D$ be curves (so $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-schemes).

Assume that $C,D$ are ***irreducible*** and $f: C \to D$ is a ***surjective*** morphism of schemes. Let $c \in C$ be a closed point.

My question is if the fiber $f^{-1}(c)$ must be in this case a ***finite*** set? What is the argument? Or conterexample?

If generally not what are the weakest conditions which garantee this?

Sure it would be a boring game if we assume that $C$ is Noetherian since the fiber as a closed subset inherits aslo this property.

Comment: I'm confused. Proper implies finite type, and so $C$ and $D$ **are** Noetherian. Then the answer is yes, always, because infinite sets are dense.

Comment: yes yes of course. then the morphism must be also proper... I see

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Although this of course answers my question I'm still curious if there exist a conterexample if we assume that $C,D$ have no more the finiteness condition. Therefore assume that they are not proper but still separated and universally closed (...and of coure futhermore irreducible). Is there a conterexample for the statement above?